# Graphics paint component and loop trouble

Tags: java, loops, paintcomponent

I can not seem to figure out why my concentric circles are not lining up. My loops seem correct to me and the measurements are correct but for some reason the last few circles are off-centered. That's the first issue I'm having. The second issue is, i can't seem to get the concentric circles to print in each square. Once again, i can't seem to find any issue in my logic, but obviously there is an issue. Any help on this at all would be great.

***This should be the end product***

[image]

***Now this is my source code- ExampleGUI.java ***

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExampleGUI {
public static void main(String args []) {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example Graphics");
    ExamplePanel panel = new ExamplePanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

*** ExamplePanel.java ***

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;



public class ExamplePanel extends JPanel{

public ExamplePanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension (600, 600));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);


    int x = 0;
    int x2 = 5;
    int y = 500;
    int y2 = 505;
    int w = 100;
    int w2 = 90;
    int h = 100;
    int h2 = 90;
    int i, j, k;

    for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        x = 0;
        x2 = x + 5;

        for(i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
            }  else {
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            }
            g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);

                for(k = 1; k < 7; k++) {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.drawOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
                    x2 = x2 + 5;
                    y2 = y2 + 5;
                    w2 = w2 - 10;
                    h2 = h2 - 10;
                }
            x = x + w;
            x2 = x2 + w2 + 10;

        }


        x = x + w;

        y = y - h;
        y2 = (y2 - h2) - 10;
    }

}
}
```

*** This is what my program looks like when i run it. It doesn't look like the other picture for some reason ***

[image]

Comment: i'd like to help you but am mesmorized by staring at the graphic. Actually i can't really tell from the graphic what you are talking about.

Comment: so... what's your problem?  Simply saying my code doesn't work is not helping people to understand your problem and offer help

Comment: The image is what i want it to look like, but my code doesn't look like that- it's very close though.

Comment: I posted my source code and i explained my issue perfectly fine.

Comment: can't you tell us how it doesn't look like the expected output?  Simply capturing your result and show to us will give us a lot better picture.

Comment: Post an image of the output you are getting too.

Comment: sure thing- ill post one now

Comment: My sincere suggestion: learn to use a debugger. Simply tracing through your code and watch change in your variable, you will see what goes wrong.  To be honest I have no idea why you write your code like this .  One thing I can tell is, if I remove the innermost loop (with k as counter), you will see green circle in each square.  It seems implies that you messed up your (poorly-named) variables in that loop.  That should be a hint big enough for you to continue your work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you "spiral" loop is modifying the state of variables that are required elsewhere

What I would do, is create a new series of variables, initialized to the current state and modify those instead...

```
                int ix = x2;
                int iy = y2;
                int ih = h2;
                int iw = w2;
                for (k = 1; k < 7; k++) {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.drawOval(ix, iy, iw, ih);
                    ix = ix + 5;
                    iy = iy + 5;
                    iw = iw - 10;
                    ih = ih - 10;
                }
```

[image]